# Is there a way to print the version of the running Apache Velocity instance in a template?

Tags: java, velocity

I have a weird problem while parsing a Velocity template which gives me an exception similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12115086/cant-create-map-in-velocity) problem where the user can't create a Map. I want to make sure that I don't use an old version of Velocity. How can I print the version of the Velocity being used in my template? (Or in any other way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check Apache Velocity version within the MANIFEST file inside velocity.jar

```
Specification-Vendor: Apache Software Foundation
Implementation-Title: org.apache.velocity
Implementation-Vendor-Id: org.apache
Implementation-Vendor: Apache Software Foundation
Implementation-Version: 1.7
```

Comment: I don't know which velocity.jar is being used. I know about the MANIFEST file but I don't know where this .jar file resides.

Comment: Maybe this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/320542/how-to-get-the-path-of-a-running-jar-file

Comment: I don't think that you understand my problem. This doesn't answer my question either.

Comment: I'm having this same problem in AWS API Gateway transformations.  We have no access to the underlying VTL libraries.